how I can Save urls of current open tabs in chrome Python
Python script to save currently open tabs in a web browser.
I need a general code can run it in different PCs
I've successfully implemented it for Firefox, and now I'm looking to extend it to support Chrome as well.

ok, what have you tried so far? and what is the specific issue you're facing with that approach? So far you've shown no attempt at trying to find how to solve this issue yourself.  This is not a free programming site

Try this code
Closer.py:
import pyautogui
from tkinter import Tk
from time import sleep
  
  SLEEP_TIME = 0.5
  MAX_DUPLICATE_COUNT = 5
  links = []
  filename = "Trial01.txt"
 
 
 def readURLs():
    pyautogui.hotkey('win', '4')      # Open Google Chrome
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    # pyautogui.position()              # To read current mouse position
    # pyautogui.moveTo(298, 69)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '1')     # Open 1st Tab
    duplicate_count = 0
    while duplicate_count < MAX_DUPLICATE_COUNT:
       pyautogui.click(x=1000, y=70, button='left')      # Click on URL Bar
       sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
       pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')                 # Select complete URL
       sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
       pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')                 # Copy URL
       sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
       link = Tk().clipboard_get()                      # Read from Clipboard
       if len(links) > 0 and link in links:            # Check if the URL has already been saved
          duplicate_count += 1
          # print('Duplicate ' + str(duplicate_count) + ' found: ' + link)
       else:
          links.append(link)                      # Else append the URL to list
       print(link)
       sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
       pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')                   # Switch to next tab
       sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    
 def saveToFile():
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    file.write('\n'.join(links  file.close()
 
 readURLs()
 saveToFile()
 pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'd')                        # Close all windows: indicates end of script

Opener:
import os
  
fileName = "Trial01.txt"
  
commandString = 'start chrome /new-window "'
file = open(fileName)
urls = file.readlines()
urls = [url.strip() for url in urls]
commandString += '" "'.join(urls) + '"'
print(commandString)
# Execute command in Command Prompt to start new Chrome window and open the URLs
os.system(commandString)


thank you ,
I need a general code can run it in different PCs
